# Wolfram: How to create a list of pie charts for the sequence of digits in 10, 20 , 30

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

> I want to be able to create multiple piecharts in a list. Each pie
>   chart is an representation of the sequence of each argument.

*Example: arguments -> 10, 20*

**arguments gets compiled into a sequence of numbers:**

`10 -> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} and 20 -> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}`

Now i need to create a list of piecharts that was formulated by those sequences.

i tried something and it worked but what if there were to be more arguments. How long would my solving code have to be to solve it:

`List[PieChart[Range[10]], PieChart[Range[20]]]`

[image]

Please help me or give me references on how to do this in a smarted way preparing for more arguments.

Comment: @Phillip Jacobs ... Please help

Comment: @DavidBullock  ... Please help

Comment: If you study *An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language* up to part 4 you will learn all you need to answer this questions for yourself.  SO generally expects people to have made a serious attempt at answering their own questions, asking a question here should be your last resort.  In the absence of any code you wrote this looks as if you expect (or just wish) someone to write code for you.  That's not how this site works.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, Thanks for your comment. I did in fact try out the question and passed but passing is not all i want to do. I want to make sure that i do stuff in the best possible way. But i updated my question so you can see what i've tried.

If you have a better way, please let me know

Comment: I'll try and keep you posted. Thank you @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark , I didn't fin help looking at Table but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Map - Wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

*So lets imagine you have **more arguments**: `{10,20,48,4.2}`*

What you want to do is [Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) each function you want to use, on each one of them.

So the functions you used was **`List, PieChart & Range`**

---

soooo....

*Map **`Range`** to each argument to turn each of them into **a sequence of 1 to 'argument' :***

```
Map[Range, {10,20,48,4.2}]
```

---

*Then map all those lists created by 'Range' to the function **`PieChart`***

```
Map[PieChart, Map[Range, {10,20,48,4.2}]]
```

Comment: This works, but `Table[PieChart[Range[n]], {n, 10, 30, 10}]` would be simpler.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That's a nice answer. Why don't you answer or edit my answer ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, Just had some nesting `{}` error on your last argument but i just tried it out and i love it. Tx bro bro ! 
`Table[PieChart[Range[n]], {n, {10, 20, 48, 4.2}}]`

Comment: The expression I posted works for me (MMA 11.something on MacOS).

Comment: Oh that's strange. Interesting though. I using MacOS as weel but I'm running 12.0 Through Parallels Desktop for Mac Business Edition
14.1.3 (45485)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark i'm also busy with the  *Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language* ... Do you know of any course i can take after that ?